# Finding a value between other values in a Pandas Dataframe for specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find a way to merge two dataframes. Each data frame uses two columns to create a unique identifier. In the master data frame the data is assigned for a given range of values, in the category data frame the data is assigned for a single value. What I'd like to do is get the type value from the master data frame for each entry in the category data frame.

It's hard to explain so here's a simple example:

```
master = {'ID1':['a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c'],
       'ID2':['d','d','d','d','d','e','e','d','e'],
       'RangeTop':[0,4,0,3,10,0,5,0,0],
       'RangeBot':[4,13,3,10,21,5,11,8,15],
       'Type':['z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r']
       }
category = {'ID1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
       'ID2':['d','d','d','e','d','e'],
       'Value':[3,8,11,7,6,13]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(master, columns = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'RangeTop','RangeBot','Type'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(category, columns = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'Value'])
df['Unique'] = df['ID1']+df['ID2']
df2['Unique'] = df2['ID1']+df2['ID2']
print(df, '\n', df2)
```

The output looks like this:

```
master
   ID1 ID2  RangeTop  RangeBot Type Unique
0   a   d         0         4    z     ad
1   a   d         4        13    y     ad
2   b   d         0         3    x     bd
3   b   d         3        10    w     bd
4   b   d        10        21    v     bd
5   b   e         0         5    u     be
6   b   e         5        11    t     be
7   c   d         0         8    s     cd
8   c   e         0        15    r     ce 
 category
   ID1 ID2  Value Unique
0   a   d      3     ad
1   a   d      8     ad
2   b   d     11     bd
3   b   e      7     be
4   c   d      6     cd
5   c   e     13     ce
```

I made up the Unique column because I thought maybe I could use the between method or the where method to find where the value is between RangeTop and RangeBot for certain Unique identifiers but it didn't work. 
What I want it to look like is:

```
 category
   ID1 ID2  Value Unique Type
0   a   d      3     ad   z
1   a   d      8     ad   y
2   b   d     11     bd   v
3   b   e      7     be   t
4   c   d      6     cd   s
5   c   e     13     ce   r
```

Comment: What's the closing on those ranges, is it [RangeTop, RangeBot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `df` has complete and non-overlapping ranges you can do this with `pd.merge_asof` to match exactly on ID then to get the value between the ranges. We'll need an additional `<` check after the merge to `NaN` any "Value"s in `df2` that are above the highest bin edge in `df`. (`direction='backward'` ensures "Value"s below the lowest bin edge are `NaN` by default).

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('Value'),      # Requires sorting
                    df.sort_values('RangeTop'),    # Requires sorting
                    by=['ID1', 'ID2'],             # Exact matching on
                    left_on='Value',         
                    right_on='RangeTop',
                    direction='backward',          # Requires Value >= RangeTop
                    allow_exact_matches=True       # [RangeTop, RangeBot) closure
                   )

# This enforces Value < RangeBot.
df2['Type'] = df2['Type'].where(df2['Value'].lt(df2['RangeBot']))
# No longer need these cols
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['RangeTop', 'RangeBot'])
```

---

```
print(df2)
# Note row order has changed due to `sort`ing

  ID1 ID2  Value Type
0   a   d      3    z
1   c   d      6    s
2   b   e      7    t
3   a   d      8    y
4   b   d     11    v
5   c   e     13    r
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what your second line (the df2['Type'] statement does. What do you mean by enforce?

Comment: @mylesmoose Imagine you had a row in `df2` that was ID1  = 'a', ID2 = 'd', with a Value of 476. Because the `asof` merge is backward, this row would get matched with the 4-13 range in `df` (as within that group 4 is the "closest" match backward). The merge did nothing to enforce that it lies `between` the range. That second line essentially adds that constraint, so it would turn that mistaken match above into `NaN`

Comment: @mylesmoose If `df` has ranges complete enough to cover all values within groups found in `df2` then that line is unnecessary as the `1:1` backward asof merge would then be the equivalent logic. But I thought that to be a rather strong assumption to make.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Look at the merge function:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=["ID1", "ID2"], right_on=["ID1", "ID2"])
```

If you only need some colums, use the drop method before or after the merge.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue that the type from df1 has to be retrieved where the value in df1 is between RangeTop and RangeBot for the unique combination of ID1 and ID2. I would need to then drop rows where value is not between RangeTop and RangeBot, which I'm also not sure how to do without using a big loop.

Comment: You are close. You would follow this merge up with a `merged[merged['Value'].ge(merged.RangeTop) & merged['Value'].lt(merged.RangeBot)]` to subset to only those rows where the Value is between the range. This allows for Values to match to multiple ranges, but also opens the possibility that you lose rows in `df2` that fall totally outside of any ranges in `df`.